# Using XPath, how can I get an exact match at tag without preceding text?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The doubt is with xpath in the given scenario:
I have this two dropdown item inside a customized dropdown component, this component has a textbox to search items that contains the informed text. Using XPath expression, I want to get the dropdown-item that exact match the informed text which I put at the textbox and not returns the dropdown-item that contains a text before the span tag. This span surround the item that match the informed criteria.

To be clearer, let's look at the html code itself where we have this issue:

This first dropdown-item, contains the item that I want to return. The span that contains text `Steak` and doesn't contains any above text, inside the div.

```
<div id="dropdown-item" role="option">
<span class="select2-match">Steak</span>
 - Delicious Salmon Steak
</div>
```

This second item, contains the item that the xpath expression should ignore, because it contains a text above the span node, inside the dropdown-item div.

```
<div id="dropdown-item" role="option">
Double
<span class="select2-match">Steak</span>
 - Monster Fillet Steak
</div>
```

I tried a lot of XPath expressions and I'm starting to think that only with XPath I won't be able to select the item I want. I know that if I concatenate two or more XPaths in programming (C# or Java, for example) and give a substring by the hyphen and in the end find the index that I need, I'll be able to find the required node, but with the amount of information I'll be working, it can not be performatic. The idea would be to use only xpath, perhaps with regex... Any suggestion?

Comment: How can two elements has the same ID (dropdown-item)?

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Believe it or not, I've found components with the same id in the projects where I worked, and this is not uncommon, I know that this isn't a 
good practice, but, It's only a example, suppose that this component has different id, or dynamic id like dropdown-item1 and dropdown-item2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible XPath (formatted for readability) :

```
//div[@id='dropdown-item']
/span[.='Steak']
     [not(
            preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]
       )
     ]
```

**brief explanation :**

- `//div[@id='dropdown-item']` : find all `div` element, anywhere in the HTML document, having `id` attribute value equals `"dropdown-item"`
- `/span[.='Steak']` : from each of such `div`, find child element `span`, having inner text exactly equals `"Steak"`....
- `[not(preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()])]` : ... and not having a non-empty preceding-sibling text node. This will match `span` having white-space only preceding sibling text, or not having any preceding sibling text at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll let you adjust the XPath to fit your needs, but here's a start:

```
//div[span[normalize-space(preceding-sibling::text())='']]
```

Comment: You probably should explain what all that XPathy stuff means so the OP will understand how to adjust it...

Comment: I considered that, but the OP has already tried a lot of XPath expressions, so I thought a nudge in the right direction might do the trick.  @Henrique, if you want a detailed breakdown, just ask.

Comment: With your xpath, I only modified this to get a exact match: //div[span[text()='Steak'][normalize-space(preceding-sibling::text())='']], thanks!